# Constant class in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants

I have read some posts about constants in `Objective-C` and I have concluded that is better to create a header and a implementation.

The problem is this. What class should I extend? `NSDocument`? Xcode does not allow me to create a class without a subclass.

Comment: what is "Constant class" ?? and how is it related to NSDocument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say simply extend `NSObject`.

I do not feel that `NSDocument` fits the purpose here, since it already has its particular purpose and not related to what you are doing here. According to the document of `NSDocument`:

> The `NSDocument` abstract class defines the interface for OS X documents. A document is an object that can internally represent data displayed in a window and that can read data from and write data to a file or file package.

Comment: Ok. But why i need extend NSObject? Just curiosity

Comment: NSObject is the root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies. It defines lots of the common behaviours of objective c objects, like alloc, init, copy etc.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean a place to declare some global constants. If that's the case, then you don't really to define a class.

To be more specific, if your constants are only primitive data and strings. You can define them in a .h file and declare them in a .m file.

Constants.h

```
extern NSString *const ConstString;
extern const NSInteger ConstInt;
```

Constants.m

```
NSString *const ConstString = @"asdasd";
const NSInteger ConstInt = 12;
```

However, if you need to define constant custom objects. Then you may need a custom singleton class for that. You can reach constants through the singleton's methods. The singelton class should be a subclass of `NSObject`, because, as @Peter Pei Guo said, that's the base class for all Objective-C classes.